# Openshift JNDI jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jndi, openshift

Im trying to get connection to my database(MYSQL) in openshift, using JNDI.
Once i get connection i make my transactions by jdbc connection.
I dont use hibernate, or any kind of container, just simple JDBC with statments,etc..

I looked to my standalone.xml, and like always that file has a datasource mysql, so i wrote my code like this.

```
String jndiName = "java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS";

Context ic = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ic.lookup(jndiName);
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) obj;
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

Commited my code to openshift server and tryied to execute my code.
First time i got connection for my database, but the second time,third,and so on, i got an error, saying that datasource doesnt exist..

Edit: error log

Unable to get managed connection for "java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS"

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about the pre-configured MySQL and PostgreSQL data sources for the Java cartridges on OpenShift Online at the following links:

- Tomcat (https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-ds.html)
- JBossAS (https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbossas-ds.html)
- JBossEAP (https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbosseap-ds.html)
- WildFly (https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-ds.html)

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for letting me know

Comment: All those links are busted ;-(